# Can you suggest any tool for automated crop/rotate of multiple images on scanned on A4 pages?

Tags: scanner, gimp, photo

Can you suggest any tool to auto crop and rotate multiple images on scanned A4 page ?

I need to scan a lot of old photos and extracting all those photos to separated files from original A4, croping and rotating it is so boring and time consuming manual work.

Is there any tool which can automate it ?

Answer (score 0):

For quite some time I'm using Gimp with [this script](http://francoismalan.com/2013/01/how-to-batch-separate-crop-multiple-scanned-photos/).